# How to set focus on the first element of a ViewChildren QueryList?

Tags: angular

**Objective**
I have a search button that returns an API response of books. After the search button is clicked, Angular/JavaScript should set focus on the first element from a ViewChildren QueryList.

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (submit)="searchBooks()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInputformControlName="term"/>
    <button aria-label="Search" mat-icon-button matSuffix>
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

<ng-container *ngIf="books$ | async as books">
    <div class="book" *ngFor="let book of books">
      <div #bookItem tabindex="-1">
        {{ book.title }}
      </div>
     ...
</ng-container>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren('bookItem') bookItem: QueryList<ElementRef>;
      searchBooks() {
        if (this.searchForm.value.term) {
          this.store.dispatch(searchBooks({ term: this.searchTerm })); // fetches books from an API
          this.bookItem.first.nativeElement.focus() // what I thought would work
         } 
      }
```

When I try to set focus I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I'm thinking this could be because of the asynchronous nature of fetching books from an API. Any idea on how to set focus to the first element of a ViewChildren list?

Comment: try with renderer2

Comment: yes its because of asyc functionality, this error is coming

Comment: Does your store have some event you can hook into when it completes the searchBooks request?  You'll need to subscribe to that.  Also note, that you may need to wait for an additional change detection cycle after that for the ViewChildren to get populated.

Comment: Please create an example on stackblatz it will help all of including u

Answer (score 0):

`this.bookItem.get(0).focus()` or  `this.bookItem.first.focus()` will set the focus for the first element of Viewchildren list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest subscribe to bookItem.changes like [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728124/after-adding-formcontrol-in-angular-how-can-i-change-focus-to-the-new-formcontro/68730697#68730697)

If you don't want make it at very early use a variable "yet" at first value=false and in searchBook equal true

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
     this.inputs.changes.subscribe(res=>{
       if (this.yet && res.length)
        res.first.nativeElement.focus()
     })
  }
```