# After adding formControl in angular how can i change focus to the new formcontrol without settimeout?

Tags: javascript, angular, focus

Hey I cannot refrence the newly created formControl with the dom as it is lagging by one row every time, it is caused due to the sync and async behaviour but cannot figure out how to over come this lag.

I have tried all the lifecycle loops but not succeded. As I have to change the focus on the dynamic row of the inputs, i have to achieve that in the meantime of the creation of the row of the inputs but it gets created visually but in the saved instance of the variable it laggs behind. that might be due to async function and the variable which i save gets initilize before it gets updated.

This is my code Blocks

```
    onAddTaka() {
    let takaNum: string = '';
    let indx = (<FormArray>this.productionForm.get('takas')).length - 1;
    if (indx >= 0) {
      let formGrp = (<FormArray>this.productionForm.get('takas')).at(indx);
      let lastTakaNumber = formGrp.value.takaNumber.split(this.serialPrefix)[1];

      takaNum = this.serialPrefix + (parseInt(lastTakaNumber) + 1);
    } else {
      takaNum = this.serialPrefix + this.serialStart;
    }

    (<FormArray>this.productionForm.get('takas')).push(
      new FormGroup({
        'takaNumber': new FormControl(takaNum, Validators.required),
        'weight': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
        'length': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)])
      })
    );
    this.onTakaNumberChange({target : { value: takaNum}},indx + 1);
  }

kd(ele, plc) {
    if(ele.keyCode == 13) {
      ele.preventDefault();
      if(ele.ctrlKey == true) {
        document.getElementById("save_btn").focus();
      }
      switch(plc){
        case 0 : ele.path[2].children[1].children[0].focus();
                break;
        case 1 : ele.path[2].children[2].children[0].focus();
                break;
        case 2 :
                this.onAddTaka();
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.updateEle();
                  this.setFocus();
                }, 1);
                break;
        default:
          this.alertMessage = "Some thing went Wrong in key Press detection Contact support!";
      }
      
    }
  }


  updateEle(){
    this.le = <HTMLElement>document.body.children[0].children[2].children[0].children[1].children[1].children[1].lastElementChild;
    if(this.le) {
      this.le = (<HTMLElement>this.le.children[0].children[0]);
    }
  }

  setFocus() {
    this.le.focus();
  }

  onTakaNumberChange(event: any, index: number) {
    let inputTakaNumber = event.target.value;
    
    this.takaNumberVerified = this.takaService.isUniqueTakaNumber(inputTakaNumber);

    if (!this.takaNumberVerified) {
      this.alertMessage = `The Taka Number (${inputTakaNumber}) is already used Try another One in row ${index + 1}`;
    }

    let str;
    if (this.takaNumberVerified) {
      str = 'form-control is-valid';
    } else {
      str = 'form-control is-invalid';
    }

    this.avgWt.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (index === i) {
        item.nativeElement.children[0].children[0].className = str;
      }
    });

  }

get controls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.productionForm.get('takas')).controls;
  }
```

This is then the html

```
<section class="container" *ngIf="voucherGenerated">
    <br>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover text-center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Taka No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Length (in mtr.)</th>
          <th scope="col">Weight</th>
          <th scope="col">Avg. Weight</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody formArrayName="takas">
        <tr *ngFor="let takaCtrl of controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i" #avgWt>
          <th scope="row">
            <input type="text" name="takaNumber" id="takaNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="W00001" formControlName="takaNumber" (keydown)="kd($event,0)" (focusout)="onTakaNumberChange($event,i)">
          </th>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="length" id="takaLength" class="form-control" placeholder="Length" formControlName="length" (keydown)="kd($event,1)" (input)="onChange($event,1,i)">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="Weight" id="takaWeight" class="form-control" placeholder="Weight" formControlName="weight" (keydown)="kd($event,2)" (input)="onChange($event,0,i)">
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="form-control">0</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onRemoveTaka(i)">X</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <div class="row mb-2 mt-2">
      <div class="col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="onAddTaka()">Add Taka</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col text-end">
        <button id="save_btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!productionForm.valid">Save Production</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: I know you don't want to do it but really the easiest thing to do is rxjs debouncetimer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template reference and ViewChildren,

```
<!--use #input in the "input" you want to make the focus-->
<-- NOT in the others, e.g. you want to focus in "takaNumber"
<input #input type="text" name="takaNumber"..>
```

The viewChildren use `{read:ElementRef}` because you want the "html tag", not the formControl

```
@ViewChildren('input',{read:ElementRef}) inputs:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

Then you has two options:

1.-when you add a new FormGroup to the array, give a breath(*) to Angular and focus the last element of the QueryList

```
onAddTaka() {
    ....
    setTimeout(()=>{
        //if you want to focus the nth-index
        //use inputs.find((_,i)=>i==index).nativeElement.focus()
        //if you want the nth
        inputs.last.nativeElement.focus()
    })
  }
```

(*)you need wait to repaint the FormArray prior to focus, so you use setInterval with "0 miliseconds"

2.- Subscribe to inputs.valueChange in ngAfterViewInit -valueChange change when we add/remove one element of the "QueryList"

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
     this.inputs.changes.subscribe(res=>{
       if (res.length)
        res.last.nativeElement.focus()
     })
  }
```