# Dynamically add a new element and focus it after rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to work out how to focus on an element that's being added dynamically and rendered from a `ngFor`.

In the template, I have a simple iterator that goes through an array of numbers and generates an input for each number:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of numbers">
  {{n}}
  <input id="number-{{n}}">
</div>

<button (click)='addNumber()'>Add 5</button>
```

I have a button at the end of the list that adds a new number.

In the .ts file I have the following:

```
// numbers is an input from parent component and is simply [1,2,3,4]

addNumber() {
  this.numbers.push(5);
  this.focusLast(5);
}
    
focusLast(number) {
  const htmlElement = document.getElementById(`number-${number}`);
  // console log shows null
  console.log(htmlElement);
  // need to select and focus on it
  htmlElement?.focus();
}
```

I can't select the last element I added as it hasn't been rendered yet and therefore I can't focus on it. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Here is my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5uwvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-component%2Fmy-component.component.ts)

Comment: To set the focus, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728124/after-adding-formcontrol-in-angular-how-can-i-change-focus-to-the-new-formcontro/68730697#68730697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED:

There are several ways to achieve this. One easy way to achieve this and to avoid direct DOM access.

In template add template reference (inputRef):

```
<div *ngFor="let n of numbers">
  {{ n }}
  <input #inputRef />
</div>
```

In ts add this:

```
  @ViewChildren('inputRef')
  set inputs(values) {
    if (values.length) {
      [...values][values.length - 1].nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem I'm actually having is a bit different to my example. I'm actually adding an input and need to focus on that input, I'll update my question to property reflect my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my example, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Ok, im writing you a new comment.